# Blazor WASM NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. "CORS Missing Allow Origin"

Tags: c#, cors, blazor, basic-authentication, preflight

In this Blazor WASM application I am simply trying to consume a third party API - I open up developer tools and see this message "CORS Missing Allow Origin" when I attempt to retrieve the data. In this case I did add         `request.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` to the request but it is still failing. I have verified this result in different browsers other than FF.

[image]

The code for the Index.Razor page is here:

```
@page "/"
@inject HttpClient Http
<h3>Presentations Scheduled</h3>

<form>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark mr-sm-2 mb-2"
                    @onclick=@(async ()=>  await GetToday())>
                Today
            </button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    @if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(errorString) == true)
    {
        <div class="h2">No Data</div>
    }
    else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(errorString) == false)
    {
        <div class="h2">@errorString</div>
    }
</form>

<div class="h2">@TestReturn</div>




@code
{
    TestModel TestReturn;
    string errorString = null;
    string TestBaseURL;
    HttpRequestMessage request;

    private async Task GetToday()
    {
        var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("user:pass");
        Http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

        string todayDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(0).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
        TestBaseURL = "https://webservices.xcompany.com/";
        UriBuilder TestURI = new UriBuilder(TestBaseURL);
        TestURI.Scheme = "https";
        TestURI.Path = "ws/run/reservations.json";
        TestURI.Query = "resource_query_id=246492";
        var TestQuery = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(TestURI.Query);
        TestQuery["scope"] = "extended";
        TestQuery["start_dt"] = todayDate;
        TestQuery["end_dt"] = todayDate;
        TestURI.Query = TestQuery.ToString();
        TestBaseURL = TestURI.ToString();
        request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, TestBaseURL);
        request.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        try
        {
            using var httpResponse = await Http.SendAsync(request);
            TestReturn = await httpResponse.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<TestModel>();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorString = $"There was a problem: {ex.Message}";
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: The real problem is that the server is responding with a 403 for OPTIONS requests to that `ws/run/reservations.json` route. The CORS message is just a side effect of that problem.

Comment: "The CORS message is just a side effect of that problem" What do you mean by that ? "a 403 for OPTIONS requests" is part of the "preflight" procedure all of which describes the communication between the browser and the server and are part and parcel of CORS. The CORS message is definitely not a side effect of the problem, but the problem itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In this case I did add request.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

You don't add such a header. You actually do nothing in this regards. It is the third party's server that has to add this header, not you.

CORS is a security feature defined as follow:

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is an HTTP-header based mechanism that allows a server to indicate (by using such a header as `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"`) any other origins (domain, scheme, or port) than its own from which a browser should permit loading of resources.

It is your browser that does not permit the loading of the resources. As far as I recall, the browser gets the response with the data, but instead of loading it, it tells you that it did not find the header `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"` in the response, therefore it refuses to load the resources.

Solution:
Ask the people in the third party API to add you to their white-list web sites that can access resources from their web site. I guess this is not practical in your case.

Since CORS is a JavaScript security feature and is only applicable when you're making a Fetch API call, you can circumvent this limitation by make a call to your own Web API that should call the third party API, gets the data and pass it back to your WebAssembly Blazor App.

Comment: I have contacted the third party and their reply is that it is "out of their scope". I should add that I am testing the visual studio code by running it from the IDE, which opens FF. I have not deployed this web application to a server.. My research suggests that might be part of the problem since it runs from localhost ?